# What should be the best way to store a percent value in SQL-Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, types

I want to store a value that represents a percent in SQL server, what data type should be the prefered one?

Comment: Do you have any examples of these "percents"?

Comment: I have few: 23.6546767%, 182%, 45%

Answer (score 64, accepted):

decimal(p, s) and numeric(p, s)

**p (precision):**

The maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored (both to the left and to the right of the decimal point)

---

**s (scale):**

The number of decimal digits that will be stored to the right of the decimal point (-> s defines the number of decimal places)

---

0 <= s <= p.

- p ... total number of digits
- s ... number of digits to the right of the decimal point
- p-s ... number of digits to the left of the decimal point

---

**Example:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
( MyDecimalColumn decimal(5,2)
 ,MyNumericColumn numeric(10,5)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES (123, 12345.12);

SELECT MyDecimalColumn, MyNumericColumn FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

Result:

```
MyDecimalColumn: 123.00 (p=5, s=2)

MyNumericColumn: 12345.12000 (p=10, s=5)
```

[link: msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Answer (score 84):

You should use [decimal(p,s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) in 99.9% of cases.

Percent is only a presentation concept: 10% is still 0.1.

Simply choose precision and scale for the highest expected values/desired decimal places when expressed as real numbers. You can have p = s for values < 100% and simply decide based on decimal places.

However, if you do need to store 100% or 1, then you'll need p = s+1.

This then allows up to 9.xxxxxx or 9xx.xxxx%, so I'd add a check constraint to keep it maximum of 1 if this is all I need.

Comment: I need a value between %100-%0, and it should allow to decimal places (i.e. %xx.xx), I am using decimal(5, 4) and it works best for me.

Comment: I've read your answer but for developers, with languages variables we have some trouble in precision when dealing with decimals. 0.2 can't be precisely represented for example, some people advises to avoid decimals in monetary calculation (for example with euros use cents of euros for calculation). groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5078068011991040 what's your advice about this ?

Comment: @Nico: Simply never use approximate numbers in a database (such as `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE`). You really don't need them and they can easily cause problems. As to cents vs. euros: That's nonsense. `DECIMAL` is a precise datatype; and storing 123.45 is thus as exact as 12345. It makes no sense not to store an amount in its currency but in a sub currency in a database; it would only confuse people and may lead thus to wrong calculations and unexpected results.

Answer (score 21):

I agree, DECIMAL is where you should store this type of number.  But to make the decision easier, store it as a percentage of 1, not as a percentage of 100.  That way you can store exactly the number of decimal places you need regardless of the "whole" number.  So if you want 6 decimal places, use DECIMAL(9, 8) and for 23.3436435%, you store 0.23346435.  Changing it to 23.346435% is a display problem, not a storage problem, and most presentation languages / report writers etc. are capable of changing the display for you.

Answer (score 10):

I think [decimal(p, s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) should be used while s represents the percentage capability.
the 'p' could of been even 1 since we will never need more than one byte since each digit in left side of the point is one hunderd percent, so the p must be at least s+1, in order you should be able to store up to 1000%.
but SQL doesn't allow the 'p' to be smaller than the s.

Examples:
28.2656579879% should be decimal(13, 12) and should be stored 00.282656579879
128.2656579879% should be decimal(13, 12) and should be stored 01.282656579879

28% should be stored in decimal(3,2) as 0.28
128% should be stored in decimal(3,2) as 1.28

Note: if you know that you're not going to reach the 100% (i.e. your value will always be less than 100% than use decimal(s, s), if it will, use decimal(s+1, s).

And so on

Comment: What are you trying to say? decimal(12, 12) can not store 01.282656579879

Comment: Why ask the question and then give a details answer immediately afterwards...?

Comment: Thanks for the tit-for-tat downvote. However, you really don't understand decimal. Why (s+1, s) for values < 100% ?

Comment: @Greg: to point out what was wrong. Shimmy thought it was correct.

Comment: I think he's conveying that you should set p/s based on your requirements for range (0-99.9, 0-9999, etc.) and precision.

Comment: @Mayo: but why (s+1, s) for less than 100%?

Comment: @gbn: s+1 is only for when greather than 100%, cuz then you have to store items that reach the first place in the unit (i.e. not smaller than 1).

Answer (score 5):

The datatype of the column should be decimal.