# Appropriate datatype for holding percent values?

Tags: sql-server, types, sqldatatypes

What is the best datatype for holding percent values ranging from 0.00% to 100.00%?

Comment: Also found this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602318/what-should-be-the-best-way-to-store-a-percent-value-in-sql-server

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Assuming two decimal places on your percentages, the data type you use depends on how you plan to store your percentages:

- If you are going to store their **fractional equivalent** (e.g. 100.00% stored as **1.0000**), I would store the data in a `decimal(5,4)` data type with a `CHECK` constraint that ensures that the values never exceed 1.0000 (assuming that is the cap) and never go below 0 (assuming that is the floor).
- If you are going to store their **face value** (e.g. 100.00% is stored as **100.00**), then you should use `decimal(5,2)` with an appropriate `CHECK` constraint.

Combined with a good column name, it makes it clear to other developers what the data is and how the data is stored in the column.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `decimal(5,2)` where 2 denotes the number of digits after the decimal separator?

Comment: @BorisCallens - Can't believe I missed that all these years. Yes, that's a typo. `decimal(5,2)` is what should be captured with a check constraint.

Comment: I assume this originally had `decimal(5,4)` and was changed to `decimal(5,2)` after the above comment... I think `decimal(5,4)` would be the better definition - i.e. you want to store 0 to 1 with 2 decimal places, not 0 to 100. The reason being a percentage is out of 100; so 100% is 100/100 which is 1. Doing it this way makes more sense for most cases (e.g. `100% * 100% = 100%`, not `10000%`; `1 * 1 = 1`).

Comment: @JohnLBevan - It spends on how they are being stored. If the values are going to stored as displayed (e.g. `100.00`) then you need `decimal(5,2)`. If the values are going to be stored as fractions (e.g. `1.0000`), then you need `decimal(5,4)`. Will update the post.

Comment: Can anyone explain why you need 4 decimal places? Cant you use 2? Like .91===91% or 1.00===100%. I'm implementing this now and was wondering the gain with 4 places. Something like Pct decimal(10, 2) CHECK (Pct>=.01 AND Pct<=1). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MichaelHanon - Depends on the requirement. The OP showed 2 decimal places so I assumed that 99.99% and 100.00% are valid values. If you want percents with 0 decimal places, then you can use `decimal(3,2)` to store them as fractions or a tinyint if you are going to store whole numbers.

Answer (score 41):

- Hold as a `decimal`.
- Add check constraints if you want to limit the range (e.g. between 0 to 100%; in some cases there may be valid reasons to go beyond 100% or potentially even into the negatives).
- Treat value 1 as 100%, 0.5 as 50%, etc.  This will allow any math operations to function as expected (i.e. as opposed to using value 100 as 100%).
- Amend precision and scale as required (these are the two values in brackets `columnName decimal(precision, scale)`.  Precision says the total number of digits that can be held in the number, scale says how many of those are after the decimal place, so `decimal(3,2)` is a number which can be represented as `#.##`; `decimal(5,3)` would be `##.###`.
- `decimal` and `numeric` are essentially the same thing.  However `decimal` is ANSI compliant, so always use that unless told otherwise (e.g. by your company's coding standards).

Example Scenarios

- For your case (0.00% to 100.00%) you'd want `decimal(5,4)`.
- For the most common case (0% to 100%) you'd want `decimal(3,2)`.
- In both of the above, the check constraints would be the same

**Example:**

```
if object_id('Demo') is null
create table Demo
    (
        Id bigint not null identity(1,1) constraint pk_Demo primary key
        , Name nvarchar(256) not null constraint uk_Demo unique 
        , SomePercentValue decimal(3,2) constraint chk_Demo_SomePercentValue check (SomePercentValue between 0 and 1)
        , SomePrecisionPercentValue decimal(5,2) constraint chk_Demo_SomePrecisionPercentValue check (SomePrecisionPercentValue between 0 and 1)
    )
```

**Further Reading:**

- Decimal Scale & Precision: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832%28SQL.80%29.aspx
- `0 to 1` vs `0 to 100`: [C#: Storing percentages, 50 or 0.50?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304177/c-storing-percentages-50-or-0-50)
- Decimal vs Numeric: [Is there any difference between DECIMAL and NUMERIC in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759401/is-there-any-difference-between-decimal-and-numeric-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hmm, I think your example scenarios are wrong. For `(0.00% to 100.00%)` you need  `decimal(5,2)` and for `(0% to 100%) ` it's better to use int if you don't need decimal points.

Comment: Hey @nacholibre; the examples are correct.  The important thing to note is that `100%` is held as `1.00`; not as `100.00`.  i.e. 100% of 5 is 5 => `1 x 5 = 5`.  50% of 90 is 45.  `0.5 x 90 = 45`.  Hope that helps to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Thomas and I would choose the DECIMAL(5,4) solution at least for WPF applications.

Have a look to the MSDN Numeric Format String to know why :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k#PFormatString

> The percent ("P") format specifier multiplies a number by 100 and converts it to a string that represents a percentage.

Then you would be able to use this in your XAML code:

```
DataFormatString="{}{0:P}"
```

Answer (score 2):

If 2 decimal places is your level of precision, then a "smallint" would handle this in the smallest space (2-bytes). You store the percent multiplied by 100.

EDIT: The [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832%28SQL.80%29.aspx) type is probably a better match. Then you don't need to manually scale. It takes 5 bytes per value.

Answer (score 0):

Use numeric(n,n) where n has enough resolution to round to 1.00. For instance:

```
declare @discount numeric(9,9)
    , @quantity int
select @discount = 0.999999999
    , @quantity = 10000

select convert(money, @discount * @quantity)
```

Comment: This question has a fairly high rated accepted answer from over three years ago. If you are looking for old questions to answer, please refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered