# Displaying percentage values in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I am trying to display values in percentage format in Gridview. Right now I am able to get percentage values along with its symbol but what i need is the Range. I am storing % values through a DropDown List which has 0% to 100% , for example if i select 20% from DropDown, it should store in my DB as 20% and the same should be displayed in my GridView but I am getting it is 2 in DB and 200% in my Grid View.

I know there is a small mistake somewhere , but I am not able to figure it out. I have stored DB data type for Percnetage as Decimal(8,0). Need help guys.

Here is what i have tried

DropDownList aspx code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DrpPercentageComplete" runat="server" BackColor="LightBlue"
 BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" 
 Font-Size="X-Small" DataTextFormatString="{0:0.# %}" ForColor="Black" Height="16px" 
                                                                onselectedindexchanged="DrpPercentageComplete_SelectedIndexChanged" 
 style="text-align: center" Width="135px">
  <asp:ListItem Value="Please Select"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="None"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="0%">0%</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="10%">10%</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="20%">20%</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="30%">30%</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="40%">40%</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="50%">50%</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="60%">60%</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="70%">70%</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="80%">80%</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="90%">90%</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="100%">100%</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

GridView TemplateField aspx code of Percentage

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="% Complete">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="PercentageComplete" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
 Font-Size="X-Small" Height="30px" Text='<%# Eval("PercentageComplete","{0:0.#%}")%>'         Width="100px">
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterStyle BackColor="LightSlateGray"  />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="LightSlateGray" ForeColor="White" Width="109px" />
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

aspx.cs code of adding ddl value

```
protected void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MTMSDTO objc = new MTMSDTO();

            int Flag = 0;

            objc.TaskName = TxtTaskName.Text;
            objc.ClientName = DrpClientName.SelectedItem.Text;

            string date;
            date = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtBeginDate.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

            objc.BeginDate = dt;
            objc.DueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtDueDate.Text);
            objc.Description = TxtDescription.Text;
            objc.AssignBy = LblAssignBy.Text;
            objc.AssignTo = DrpAssignTo.SelectedItem.Text;
            objc.Status = DrpStatus.SelectedItem.Text;
            objc.PercentageComplete = Convert.ToInt32(DrpPercentageComplete.Text);

            int X = obj.InsertTask(objc);
            {
                if (X >= 0)
                {
                    Flag = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    Flag = 0;
                }
            }

            if (Flag == 1)
            {
                LblSuccess.Visible = true;
                LblSuccess.Text = "Data Added Successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                LblErr.Visible = true;
                LblErr.Text = "Failed To Add Data!!!";
            }
    }

 private Decimal _PercentageComplete;

    public Decimal PercentageComplete
    {
        get { return _PercentageComplete; }
        set { _PercentageComplete = value; }
    }

public int InsertTask(MTMSDTO M)
    {
        DBAccess db = new DBAccess();

        SqlParameter objParam = new SqlParameter("@TaskID", M.TaskID);
        objParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Task_Name", M.TaskName));
        db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Client_Name", M.ClientName));
        db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Begin_Date", M.BeginDate));
        db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Due_Date", M.DueDate));
        db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description_A", M.Description));
        db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Assign_By", M.AssignBy));
        db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Assign_To", M.AssignTo));
        db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status_S", M.Status));
        db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Percentage_Complete", M.PercentageComplete));
        db.Parameters.Add(objParam);

        int retval = db.ExecuteNonQuery("InsertTask");

        if (retval >= 1)
        {
            return int.Parse(objParam.Value.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

stored procedure to insert

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTask]


   @Task_Name nvarchar(50),
   @Client_Name nvarchar(50),
   @Begin_Date date,
   @Due_Date date,
   @Description_A nvarchar(50),
   @Assign_By nvarchar(50),
   @Assign_To nvarchar(50),
   @Status_S nvarchar(50),
   @Percentage_Complete decimal(18,0),

   @TaskID bigint OUTPUT

   As

   Insert into dbo.Task
   (
    TaskName, 
    ClientName, 
    BeginDate,
    DueDate,
    Description,
    AssignBy,
    AssignTo,
    Status,
    PercentageComplete
   )

    Values
   (
    @Task_Name, 
    @Client_Name, 
    @Begin_Date,
    @Due_Date,
    @Description_A,
    @Assign_By,
    @Assign_To,
    @Status_S,
    @Percentage_Complete
   )

   Select @TaskID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just save the value in database as Decimal/varchar without any symbols ie(%).
And on gridview use `string.Concat` to add the `%` symbol after your DB value

Code look like :

```
<asp:Label ID="PercentageComplete" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
 Text='<%# string.Concat(Eval("PercentageComplete"),"%") %>'>
```

**Edited:**

Edit your DropdownList Markup as written in below code, asyou are trying to convert it into `int32` you cant use **`%`**. Also you may have decimal value so convert it into decimal

```
<asp:ListItem Value="0">0%</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="10">10%</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="20">20%</asp:ListItem>
    .............
    ............
<asp:ListItem Value="100">100</asp:ListItem>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
objc.PercentageComplete = Convert.ToDecimal(DrpPercentageComplete.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: paaji .. thnks for the above code.. i tried it... problem is if i select any value between 0% to 100% from dropdown its taking as single digit .. i mean if i select 20% it takes as 2 in my DB and same is displaying in Gridview... 2%

Comment: @Suraj:  Pls post your serverside code, how you inserting ddl value into  DB

Comment: objc.PercentageComplete = Convert.ToInt32(DrpPercentageComplete.Text); but its giving error: input string is not in correct format and if i give ToString or ToDecimal its saying cannot convert into any of those

Answer (score 3):

This is the best way to store percent values in DB.

It's **`decimal(p, s)`**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Comment: thnks for the reply... but im storing it as d same way decimal(p,s).. but unable to get needed value...

Comment: Try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602318/what-should-be-the-best-way-to-store-a-percent-value-in-sql-server

Comment: i followed the same question and tried formatting my code sir :)

Answer (score 0):

You should save the values without any simbol in db, as decimals. When you need format in the UI, cal ToString and use the rigth format for percentage:

```
1 ("P", en-US) -> 100.00 %

1 ("P", fr-FR) -> 100,00 %

-0.39678 ("P1", en-US) -> -39.7 %

-0.39678 ("P1", fr-FR) -> -39,7 %
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dwhawy9k.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString