# What would be the best datatype to use to store a simple number up to 99.99

Tags: sql-server

I see there's a variety of different datatypes but I just want something small and simple that will store a number up to 99.999 and the last digit does not even have to be accurate?  Can someone tell me which would be the most suitable and smallest datatype that I could use for this?

Comment: do you numbers represent a percentage?

Comment: What sort of things will you *do* with this number, being merely storing it? Will you be performing any form of mathematics upon it? If so, what sort of operations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should be the best way to store a percent value in SQL-Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602318/what-should-be-the-best-way-to-store-a-percent-value-in-sql-server)

Comment: I am storing word frequency so it does not even need to be accurate and I would not be doing any math on it.  If I used a decimal what numbers should I put in parenthesis after?

Comment: Make it a rule never to use approximate datatypes such as `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE`. You don't need them in a database. Use `DECIMAL` for decimal numbers. In your case `DECIMAL(5,3)` for five digits in total of which three are decimal places. This may cost you a byte or two compared with `FLOAT`, but who cares actually? Simply pretend `FLOAT` doesn't exist :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `DECIMAL(4,2)` which would allow you to store `-99.99` to `99.99`

- The 4 represents the precision which is the total number of digits
  that can be stored (to the left and right of the decimal place).
- The 2 represents the scale which is the number of digits that can
  appear after the decimal place.

Answer (score 3):

float(24) would be the best one for your scenario. It will consume 4 bytes which is lower than Decimal/Numeric datatype with lowest precision(5 bytes).

[MSDN - float](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx)

[MSDN - decimal/numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)